# How to update sales_order_grid table in M2 production mode?

Tags: magento2, order-grid

We have a working, well filled `sales_order_grid` table. But those orders we add via custom integration do not show up there - or show up, but with a very long delay.

We found in the `cron_schedule` table that three jobs are running: `sales_grid_order_async_insert`, `sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert` and `sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert` - but they never finish.

Is there a way to re-synchronize the entire `sales_order_grid` table? Would it re-fill if we truncate it? Or can we run the `sales_grid_order_async_insert` manually? Is there an *easy* way to debug it?

Some answers to other questions refer to options that are only available in Magento2 developer mode, but do not apply to production mode.

Answer (score 1):

We solved it by increasing the value of the mysql setting `max_allowed_packet`. The default value is 4 MB, according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html

Afterwards, we deleted the running cron jobs, and then the indexes ran successfully.